# Как сравнить две колонки с предложениями разбивая их по пробелу и сравнивая каждое слово?

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблица и в ней две колонки:

```
col1                  col2
--------------------- -------------------------
best buy card credit  credit no take buy order
```

Длина колонок не фиксирована, т.е. количество слов может быть любое.
Нужно сравнить слова в обоих столбцах и вернуть количество совпадающих слов.

Ожидаемый результат - 2 слова `buy, credit`.

Каким запросом можно добится этого?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Match the words in two columns oracle sql by breaking the string and comparing each word](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18757728) от участника [@user2342436](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2342436/user2342436)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/18757728

Answer (score 2):

Преобразовать обе колонки в табличные значения, затем полученые таблицы соединить.

Воспроизводимый пример:

```
create table t (id int, col1 varchar2 (96), col2 varchar2 (96))
/
insert all 
    into t values (1, 'best buy card credit', 'credit no take buy order') 
    into t values (2, 'aaa bbb ccc', 'ccc ddd fff') 
    into t values (3, 'aaa bbb ccc', 'zzz yyy xxx') select * from dual; 

with t1 (id, col, val) as (
    select id, col1, trim (column_value)
    from t, xmlTable (('"'||replace (t.col1, ' ', '","')||'"')) x
),
t2 (id, col, val) as (
    select id, col2, trim (column_value)
    from t, xmlTable (('"'||replace (t.col2, ' ', '","')||'"')) x
)
select t1.id, 
    listagg (t2.val, ',') within group (order by t2.val) "words", 
    count (t2.id) "total matched"
from t1 
left join t2 on (t2.id = t1.id and t2.val = t1.val)
group by t1.id
/
```

Результат:

```
        ID words            total matched
---------- ---------------- -------------
         1 buy,credit                   2
         2 ccc                          1
         3                              0
```